# SQL Access QUERY to show duplicate

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below table in SQL Access and I want to find out which products have 2 distinct categories.

For example the product `abc` has only one category, so I don't want it to show up in my query, but product `def` has both categories, so I want it to show up.

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | Product | Category |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | abc     | A        |
|  2 | abc     | A        |
|  3 | def     | B        |
|  4 | def     | A        |
|  5 | abc     | A        |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer ultimately depends on whether you are looking for products which are assigned to **more than one** category, or **exactly 2 categories** as you state in your question:

> I want to find out which products have **2 distinct categories**.

For the latter, you might use something like the following:

```
select t.product
from (select distinct product, category from YourTable) t
group by t.product
having count(*) = 2
```

For the former, there are many possible options - you can simply change the equality operator `=` in the above query to a greater than or equal to operator `>=` yielding:

```
select t.product
from (select distinct product, category from YourTable) t
group by t.product
having count(*) >= 2
```

Or you could use a `where exists` clause to test whether there exists at least one other record for the same `product` assigned to a different `category`:

```
select distinct t.product 
from YourTable t
where exists 
(select 1 from YourTable u where u.product = t.product and u.category <> t.category)
```

Or you could use aggregation with a `min/max` test within the `having` clause, as per query suggested by @forpas.

---

In all of the above examples, change `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Answer (score 1):

Access does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` so for your sample data a `HAVING` clause where you set the condition that the minimum Category is different than the maximum Category will do:

```
select Product
from tablename
group by Product
having min(Category) <> max(Category)
```